# Why does this Python module import a class from the same module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I'm looking at the source for `gunicorn`, which is a very popular project.

In the [gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py#L66) module, the module defines a class, and then imports the class from the same file:

```py
class WSGIApplication(Application):
    ...

def run():
    from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import WSGIApplication
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
```

The class is defined in the same module, up above.
Why would it need to import it?

If I comment out the first line of the `run()` function (the import line), gunicorn runs perfectly fine (doesn't crash) - at least in the way I'm running it, with: `gunicorn mysite.wsgi:application`, `mysite` being the name of my test Django project.

This being a high-profile project, if this import was unnecessary, I assume someone would have removed it by now. Is there a reason for this import?

Comment: "This being a high-profile project, if this import was unnecessary, I assume someone would have removed it by now. I" Oh my sweet Summer child...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The import is indeed unnecessary, although it does not hurt either.

If you "git blame" the line, you'll find in [this commit](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/commit/c239a3cd88542c0cab4f35c785d710d38df98216) that this `run` function was simply copied and pasted from a separate `main.py`, which used to require this import to work. This `main.py` was deleted in the same commit.

Comment: Yeah, this looks like a typical sloppy (or perhaps automated) refactoring artifact.

Comment: I'm trying to learn more about Python, and web development by studying some popular projects. I guess no code base is perfect.